# Object not shown on Canvas (WPF Application)

Tags: c#, wpf, oop, canvas, 2d

In this Application, i have a car class with a method called Spawn (which should draw the object on a Canvas which i defined in the XAML file). I call the Method in MainWindow, but when I run my program, there is no car being drawn onto the Canvas.

Here is the Spawn method:

```cs
        public void Spawn(Canvas cvs)
        {
            cvs = new Canvas();
            cvs.Children.Clear();

            carBody.Width = 70;
            carBody.Height = 120;
            carBody.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Color);

            Canvas.SetLeft(carBody, SpawnLocation.X);
            Canvas.SetTop(carBody, SpawnLocation.Y);

            Rectangle[] tires = new Rectangle[4];
            Rectangle[] windows = new Rectangle[2];
            Label lblBrand = new Label();

            RotateTransform rotation = new RotateTransform();

            // Reifen
            tires[0] = new Rectangle()
            {
                Fill = Brushes.Black,
                Width = 20,
                Height = 30
            };

            Canvas.SetLeft(tires[0], -9);
            Canvas.SetTop(tires[0], 18);

            tires[1] = new Rectangle()
            {
                Fill = Brushes.Black,
                Width = 20,
                Height = 30
            };

            Canvas.SetLeft(tires[1], 61);
            Canvas.SetTop(tires[1], 18);

            tires[2] = new Rectangle()
            {
                Fill = Brushes.Black,
                Width = 20,
                Height = 30
            };

            Canvas.SetLeft(tires[2], -9);
            Canvas.SetTop(tires[2], 80);

            tires[3] = new Rectangle()
            {
                Fill = Brushes.Black,
                Width = 20,
                Height = 30
            };

            Canvas.SetLeft(tires[3], 61);
            Canvas.SetTop(tires[3], 80);

            // Fenster
            windows[0] = new Rectangle() // Front
            {
                Fill = Brushes.White,
                Width = 50,
                Height = 40
            };

            Canvas.SetLeft(windows[0], 0);
            Canvas.SetTop(windows[0], 0);

            windows[1] = new Rectangle() // rear
            {
                Fill = Brushes.White,
                Width = 50,
                Height = 50
            };

            Canvas.SetLeft(windows[1], 0);
            Canvas.SetTop(windows[1], 0);

            // Label Automarke
            lblBrand.Width = 40;
            lblBrand.Height = 23;
            lblBrand.Content = Brand;

            // Add2Canvas
            for (int i = 0; i < tires.Length; i++)
                carBody.Children.Add(tires[i]);
            for (int i = 0; i < windows.Length; i++)
                carBody.Children.Add(windows[i]);
            carBody.Children.Add(lblBrand);

            if (Direction == "nord")
            {
                rotation.Angle = 0;
                rotation.CenterX = SpawnLocation.X;
                rotation.CenterY = SpawnLocation.Y;

                carBody.RenderTransform = rotation;
            }
            else if (Direction == "süd")
            {
                rotation.Angle = 180;
                rotation.CenterX = SpawnLocation.X;
                rotation.CenterY = SpawnLocation.Y;

                carBody.RenderTransform = rotation;
            }
            else if (Direction == "west")
            {
                rotation.Angle = 90;
                rotation.CenterX = SpawnLocation.X;
                rotation.CenterY = SpawnLocation.Y;

                carBody.RenderTransform = rotation;
            }
            else if (Direction == "ost")
            {
                rotation.Angle = 270;
                rotation.CenterX = SpawnLocation.X;
                rotation.CenterY = SpawnLocation.Y;

                carBody.RenderTransform = rotation;
            }

            cvs.Children.Add(carBody);
        }
```

Calling the methodMainWindow:

```cs
        Car car1;
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            car1 = new Car("Audi", Colors.Red);
            car1.Direction = "west";
            car1.SpawnLocation = new Point(550, 340);
            car1.Spawn(gameScreen);
        }
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it! I initialized the argmument of my Spawn method, it now works after I deleted it.

My method looked like this first:

```cs
        public void Spawn(Canvas cvs)
        {
            cvs = new Canvas();
            cvs.Children.Clear();

            carBody.Width = 70;
```

I initialized my the Argument, but since i don't wanna create a new Canvas, i deleted these two first lines of my method.

```cs
        public void Spawn(Canvas cvs)
        {

            carBody.Width = 70;
            carBody.Height = 120;
            carBody.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Color);
```

Now its working fine.

Comment: It's fine to answer your own question, but I suggest being more specific with how you fixed it. Consider that others may find your question useful and therefore want to know how to fix their code.